# Dimension Tables: is it worth creating a dimension with only 2 values?

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence

Is it worth creating a dimension that has only 2 values?

The values are literally "Yes" and "No".

Or should I combine it with other values and turn it into a junk dimension?

**Edit:**

Not sure why this was closed as it's not opinion based, it's based on the number of records, etc.

Query performance does not seem to be much impacted if you are joining with a table that has just a couple rows, but rather than having a bunch of joins with tables that will likely contain no more than 2-3 values, it's better to just create a junk dimension and do 1 join.

Seems the best solution for my problem was to just turn it into a junk dimension.

Comment: Third option, simple define Y/N column it the fact table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, Yes.  It is worth creating a dimension containing all the possible values for an attribute.

The purpose of a junk dimension is to combine those very tiny dimensions into a larger table to eliminate unnecessary joins.  Even if this single Yes/No value is the only attribute with such a small set, it is still worth creating a junk dimension because...

Warehouses grow.  You will eventually find other attributes that are great candidates for including in the junk dimension (sex/gender, marital status, deceased, etc). Start your warehouse on a good path by doing it right the first time.

It might seem like overkill, but the system doesn't care much about joining to a two row table. It is much easier to add new attributes to an existing junk dimension versus rewriting your architecture when needed later.  Also, once you publish the design for use, your users will have queries leveraging those attributes.  That makes change extremely difficult, if not impossible.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, creating a junk dimension. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use both Static Dimension or Junk dimension :

**Static Dimensions**

Static dimensions are not extracted from the original data source, but are created within the context of the data warehouse. A static dimension can be loaded manually — for example with status codes — or it can be generated by a procedure, such as a date or time dimension. Also, status codes dimension is mostly a static dimension.

**Junk Dimensions**

There are some attributes that have really low cardinality (distinct possible values). Neither this attributes specifically belong to a dimension table nor they are important enough to create an individual dimension for them. A junk dimension creates combinations of all the distinct values of such attributes and stores it in a single junk dimension table. The surrogate keys for these rows are inserted in the fact table. So now the fact table instead of having multiple foreign keys for each of these attributes, has a single foreign key for each row in the junk dimension table

Example-: Status( pass, fail) Income category( lower, middle, high)

Note: Be careful, another dimension = more joins = complex queries